# What does ! mean on a Kotlin return value?

Tags: null, kotlin

I'm trying to use a `Task` `result` that has a type of `Location!`. What does that mean for how I am supposed to handle nullability? Could it be null or not?

I couldn't find this kind of declaration in the [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) section of [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org).

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types

Comment: I would suggest [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IhT8HACc2E) by Andrey Breslav.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Type notated with `!` is called **platform type**, which is a type *coming from Java* and thus can most probably be `null`. It’s what the Kotlin compiler infers by default when calling Java (for the most basic cases, Java methods can be [annotated](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) to get around this). You should handle platform types as *nullable* types, unless you certainly know that the particular API will never return `null`. The compiler allows platform types to be assigned to variables of both nullable and non-null types.

> **[Notation for Platform Types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)**
>
> [...]
>
> `T!` means "`T or T?`" [...]

You could refer to platform types as "types of **unknown nullability**". Also important to know is that you cannot use the exclamation-marked type for your own types, it's not part of the Kotlin syntax, it's only a notation.